# Change TimeZone for DateTime object

Tags: date, dart, timezone

I have a Dart [DateTime](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) object. I need to change the Time Zone, we'll say from Eastern to Central. The catch is, I don't want it to set the time an hour back, I want to keep the time but just change the time zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to change the time zone without affecting the date. Use the following code:

```dart
DateTime.parse(date.toString().substring(0, 23) + '-0500');
```

This will set the time zone for the following date to UTC-5.

Comment: Likely this will take the offset into consideration when parsing, but from the docs it seems that the object itself can't be anchored to anything but UTC or local time.  (What does `isUtc` give?)

Answer (score 0):

From the docs page you linked:

> A DateTime object is anchored either in the UTC time zone or in the local time zone of the current computer when the object is created.
>
> Once created, neither the value nor the time zone of a DateTime object may be changed.